# Mostrar dados se existir e Data Mostrar Idade

Tags: php

Tenho duas dúvidas. 
Tenho um código que mostra vários dados e quero apenas mostrá-los se alguns valores existirem. Vejam o código a seguir:

```
echo' <div class="tabla7">
<p><div class="titulo7">Nome</div><div class="titulo7">Data Nascimento</div><div    class="titulo7">Idade</div><div class="titulo7">Categoria Profissional</div>
<div class="titulo7">Data Entrega EPIS</div><div class="titulo7">Validade FAM</div><div class="titulo7">Credenciais</div></p>


 <p>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["Nome1"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["DataNascimento1"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> idade</div>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["Funcao1"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["EPISValidade"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["MedicaValidade"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> <a href="TrabalhadorMostrar1.php?id='.$exibe['id'].'"> Ver Credenciais </a></div>
 </div>


  //Mostrar apenas se existir o Nome2


 echo' <div class="tabla7">
<p><div class="titulo7">Nome</div><div class="titulo7">Data Nascimento</div><div class="titulo7">Idade</div><div class="titulo7">Categoria Profissional</div>
 <div class="titulo7">Data Entrega EPIS</div><div class="titulo7">Validade FAM</div><div class="titulo7">Credenciais</div></p>


 <p>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["Nome2"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["DataNascimento2"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> Idade2</div>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["Funcao2"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["EPISValidade2"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["MedicaValidade2"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> <a href="TrabalhadorMostrar2.php?id='.$exibe['id'].'"> Ver       Credenciais </a></div>
 </div>
```

Apenas quero mostrar o segundo conjunto de dados se o Nome2 estiver preenchido.

Além disso, tenho outra duvida: consigo mostrar a idade de um trabalhador utilizando apenas a data de nascimento?

Comment: Sim, faça uma condição que verifique o conteúdo de `nome2` e  para a idade, faça uma função estática que retorne o resultado da data corrente subtraindo a data de nascimento.

Comment: Mas não existe uma forma tipo: Now() - DataNascimento ou algo assim?

Comment: Sim, existe, `date('d/m/Y')`, mas observe que a formatação precisa ser igual ao do seu banco, para comparar dados dinâmicamente.

Comment: Então, você entendeu como usar? Deu certo? é uma boa prática sinalizar se a resposta ajudou ou não, caso sim, pode marcá-la como aceita.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
echo' <div class="tabla7">
<p><div class="titulo7">Nome</div><div class="titulo7">Data Nascimento</div><div    class="titulo7">Idade</div><div class="titulo7">Categoria Profissional</div>
<div class="titulo7">Data Entrega EPIS</div><div class="titulo7">Validade FAM</div><div class="titulo7">Credenciais</div></p>


 <p>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["Nome1"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["DataNascimento1"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> idade</div>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["Funcao1"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["EPISValidade"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["MedicaValidade"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> <a href="TrabalhadorMostrar1.php?id='.$exibe['id'].'"> Ver Credenciais </a></div>
 </div>


 <?php if(!empty($exibe["Nome2"])): ?>


 echo' <div class="tabla7">
<p><div class="titulo7">Nome</div><div class="titulo7">Data Nascimento</div><div class="titulo7">Idade</div><div class="titulo7">Categoria Profissional</div>
 <div class="titulo7">Data Entrega EPIS</div><div class="titulo7">Validade FAM</div><div class="titulo7">Credenciais</div></p>


 <p>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["Nome2"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["DataNascimento2"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> <?php echo (date('d/m/Y') - $exibe["DataNascimento2"]); ?></div>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["Funcao2"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["EPISValidade2"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["MedicaValidade2"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> <a href="TrabalhadorMostrar2.php?id='.$exibe['id'].'"> Ver       Credenciais </a></div>
 </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Outra forma de fazer é tornando seu array de resultados com um índice por objeto.

Exemplo:

```
 echo' <div class="tabla7">
 <p><div class="titulo7">Nome</div><div class="titulo7">Data Nascimento</div><div    class="titulo7">Idade</div><div class="titulo7">Categoria Profissional</div>
 <div class="titulo7">Data Entrega EPIS</div><div class="titulo7">Validade FAM</div><div class="titulo7">Credenciais</div></p>

 <?php foreach($exibe as $trabalhador): ?>

 <p>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$trabalhador["Nome"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$trabalhador["DataNascimento"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> <?php echo (date('d/m/Y') - $trabalhador["DataNascimento"]); ?></div>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$trabalhador["Funcao"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$trabalhador["EPISValidade"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$trabalhador["MedicaValidade"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> <a href="TrabalhadorMostrar.php?id='.$trabalhador['id'].'"> Ver Credenciais </a></div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Sobre a forma alternativa da sintaxe do foreach ou do if:
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: meto php dentro de php? 
é que tenho mais dados: Nome3, Nome4,Nome5 ....

Comment: Uma dúvida, porque você não indexou em um array desta forma:
`$exibe[0]['Nome'], $exibe[1]['Nome']` ao invés de `$exibe['Nome1']` ? Depois é só aplicar um `foreach` e tornar tudo dinâmico. Ia reduzir bastante seu HTML, você faz apenas uma diagramação HTML para cada resultado do índice `$exibe['x']`... Vou postar outra resposta...

Comment: Mas eu so estou a utilizar php. O codigo que postei é php

Comment: É php com HTML, php é server-side, html é apenas client-side, você pode usar html dentro de php.